# Laravel, getting specific array index from session

Tags: php, laravel, session

Currently, I'm dumping an array that is held within my laravel session, which successfully dumps the array:

```
<?php dd(Session::get('Tokens'));?>
```

This dumps an array with three elements, each with its own index

```
array(
   "userToken":"value",
   "secondToken":"value",
   "thirdToken":"value",
);
```

I keep running into errors trying to get specifically the userToken. I've tried `get('Tokens[userToken]')` but It's expecting a string only

How should I change this to be able to access any array key specifically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array dereferencing and add a required index directly to value, returned by `Session::get('Tokens')`:

```
echo Session::get('Tokens')['userToken'];
```

Comment: Yes, that got it! Thanks so much. I'll accept this as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 2):

you can try this too

```
$value = session('Tokens');
```

and you can use $value like and array and you'll be able to call each value with the index like

```
$value['userToken']
```

hope it help